# Как сравнить 2 массива типа char

Tags: c, массивы, char, сравнение

допустим, у меня есть 2 массива типа char `char a1[10]` и `char a2[10]`

Соответственно, они используются у меня как строка, могу ли я их как-то сравнить? Например в а1 занесено "привет", в а2 - "привет", соответственно они равны.

Можно ли сравнить целиком `a1 == a2` ??? или только посимвольно???

Comment: посимвольно или strcmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C строка - это массив из char, заканчивающийся байтом с кодом 0x00.
Если у вас это соблюдается (нулевой байт в конце строки), то можно использовать функции сравнения строк, например,

```
int strcmp( const char * string1, const char * string2 )
```

она производит лексикографическое сравнение и возвращает: 
-1, если строка string1 "меньше" строки string2;
0, если строки равны,
1, если  строка string1 "больше" строки string2.

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё упомянуть функцию `strncmp` - с указанием длины. Можно использовать без терминального нуля.